# Get the right value out of the right array-entry in MongoDB / Twig

Tags: arrays, mongodb, symfony, twig

I'm trying to get a value from an array inside a mongodb collection.

My db entries look like:

```
_id : "somerandomid"
page : "page1"
entries : [ {
            id : "id1"
            entry : "content"
           }

           {
            id : "id2"
            entry : "content2"
           } ]
```

I want to match `page : "page1"` first, then find the right entry in the 'entries' array based on 'id', then display the 'content' of that entry.

I tried: `{% set rightentry = mydb.find({page : "page1", id : "id1" }) %}`

```
{{rightentry.content}}
```

but that doesn't give me anything back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to retrieve only the subdocument that matches your query from MongoDB directly.

You'll want to iterate over the `entries` that are returned with your retrieved document to find the one that matches:

```
{% set document = mydb.find({page:"page1", "entries.id":"id1"}) %}
{% for entry in document.entries %}
    {% if entry.id === "id1" %}
        {# display contents #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.page.find({page:"page1", "entries.id":"id1"})
```

this will bring back the desired results.